# How to make inner HTML a random number and check if it matches the input

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create something much more than what I am showing, but I ran into a problem that stumped me, I essentially want to use the method `Math.floor(Math.random()*11)` to generate a random number. I then want to make the inner HTML of a `<p>` , for instance, and also have an input box that you must type that number into, click submit, and if the input equals the random number, I can then add the inner HTML of another `<p>` to "Correct" or something along the lines of that. So far no luck. The code looks like it should work. Does anyone know how to fix this code without changing it drastically?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Math Facts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="problem"></p>
    <input id="text_a" type="text" />
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
    
    <script>
   function myFunction()
{
 const a=document.getElementById("text_a").value;
    var num =  Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
    document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML = num;
if (a==num)
  {
document.getElementById("answer").innerText="Correct!";
  }
else
  {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Oops!";
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I attempted to:

1. Generate number
2. Add it to inner HTML
3. Check if the input equaled the random number

Nothing worked.

Comment: what's not working? Your code works fine - I've made it into a snippet, you'll see I made absolutely no changes to your code

Comment: Did you run it? Because when I run it through VS Code it doesn't work.

Comment: `run it through VS Code` ... I've never used VSCode to **run** a web page - run the snippet I created for you in your question using your code unchanged - then, tell me what's wrong

Comment: Weird... Its annoying that it doesn't work on VS Code...

Answer (score 0):

There's one issue that might be causing the problem. The innerHTML property of the problem paragraph is being set to the random number (num), but you want to display a mathematical expression instead. Additionally, you should parse the input value as an integer for a proper comparison.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Math Facts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="problem"></p>
    <input id="text_a" type="text" />
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
    
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const a = parseInt(document.getElementById("text_a").value);
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
            document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML = `What is ${num} + x?`;
            if (a === num) {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerText = "Correct!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Oops!";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes made:

- Used a template literal to display a mathematical expression in the "problem" paragraph.
- Converted the input value (`a`) to an integer using `parseInt` for a proper comparison.

Comment: odd that this works in vscode and your code doesn't @LoganMcDermott - perhaps you mistyped your code in the question

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I would like to display the random number in problem right as the code is run, I am trying to access the variable "a" outside of the function but that doesn't work. Just for clarification, when you press "check", it displays the previous problem.